# The "TADA!" sound effect sounds wrong when I play it

Tags: theory, piano, chords

It's obviously very much a beginner's question. While attempting to play this ["TADA" sound effect](https://chordify.net/chords/sound-effect-tada-baniger3711), I noticed that on the website it's written just C. But when I press C twice it does not sound the same. How to achieve this?

Comment: If one looks closely, the underlying problem here isn't "what chords do I play". It's actually a problem of understanding what a chord is and how they are written and abbreviated. Voted to reopen, as that should clearly be on-topic. Surely "what is a chord" is indeed useful to future readers?

Comment: Also, since OP said "*press* C", I took that to mean this questioneer was playing the piano. If that is untrue, OP, feel free to correct it.

Comment: I can easily understand how the OP can't identify it as a chord, not a single note. Like, if you play a single note on a General MIDI synth's "Orch Hit" sound, for many people it's not at all obvious that the sample might actually contain an entire major or minor chord played by an orchestra, not just a unison note. This sort of basic understanding and perception of sound has been ruled out as "off topic" for the topic of Practice and Theory of Music, by some people.

Comment: I misunderstood the question; I thought this was a "what notes do I play?" question, but I see now that there's a deeper underlying issue. Mea culpa!

Comment: The website has diagrams on the linked page that show exactly what notes to play on several instruments.

Comment: Even better, the website has different voicing for each instrument

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica you are 100% right. I really don't know where to start to understand these. I try to play this sound with a synthesizer(?) with a programming library. You can also see the same question which I asked on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655907/create-sound-effect-with-tone-js-notes/68656214?noredirect=1#comment121345204_68656214 - I see the notes.. but I still don't get how to create the same sound-effect. Any tutorials which help to understand the basics are highly welcome! thank you for reopening!

Comment: In fairness, nowhere is 'just play a C note' found. There are three chords shown, guitar, uke and piano, all of which show *chords*. And, the sound effect played sounds nothing like a single note, or even unison notes.

Comment: At least a part of the mystery behind the question is the notation - what does "C" mean - and possibly not knowing about the concept of chords. A lot of the questions here are more like customer support requests. "I went to this site, saw this stuff, interpreted it as so-and-so, and tried to act accordingly, but got _this_ sound instead of the other sound I had expected. What is wrong?"

Comment: @Tim "sounds nothing like a single note, or even unison" Well, to *you*. I could see that being misheard pretty easily.

Comment: @user45266 - Not being unkind. OP tried just C notes, and realised that that wasn't the sound. What other options were available? Playing the *chord*, which was what the site said. Had OP done that, maybe the question wouldn't be needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I checked the link with another browser and could actually see what exactly the notation was... I still think that it's a valid beginner question, but for slightly different reasons. ;) Here are the relevant bits from Chordify.net:

[image: Chordify.net sound effect TADA]

Yes, it has the letter "C", but it's not only the name of a single note, here it is a *chord symbol*, an abbreviation meaning the C major chord. In a chord, multiple different notes are played at the same time. To play a C major chord, you play the notes C, E and G. The chord symbol for a C minor chord is "Cm" and it has the notes C, *Eb* (E flat) and G.

[image: Chordify.net explained]

When you see the letter C, you have to figure out from the context, whether it means the C note, or the C major chord, or e.g. a time signature. In a time signature "C" means "common time", 4/4.

[image: C as time signature]

This a valid question, and the notation is not self-evidently clear. If you know that "C" can mean a note, you may not know that it can also mean a chord, which is a different thing. Or if you know how to play "C" on the guitar or ukulele, you may not have realized that the thing you played was a chord, not a single note. I recently had to explain this to a beginner guitarist who had been playing "C" and other such things on the guitar, but had not been told about chords and notes. That information opened a new world for him. :)

In the following pictures, the letter C is used in two different meanings: chord symbol and note name.

[image: C major piano diagram explanation]

[image: C major guitar diagram explanation]

Comment: Missed a few opportunities for a freehand circle or two :)

Answer (score 6):

It's not just a note - it's a major chord. So using C as the example, you need to play C E G, or C E G C. Play around with those notes, to find what you hear is the best combination. Maybe a lower C note will do it for you.

Comment: Harmony makes everything better! Adding vocals helps :)

Comment: What is it that the dver doesn't understand/like about this answer? Come on, be brave!

Comment: @Tim I have a life.

Comment: We all do, but I still don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Tim what you mean by "dver"?

Comment: A 'dver' is shorthand (mine) for downvoter. Someone who downvotes questions and answers - often with no obvious reason. And I feel it's important for that reason to be explained - otherwise we're just left in ignorance. Probably due to there being a lot of protection in anonymity - 'no-one's going to do anything 'cos I'm invisible/untraceable...'

Comment: aha sorry didn't know. lol - I would never downvote an effort from another guy who tries to help me.. it wasn't me :) I am happy for any help! cheers!